# ServiceTestCase<T>.getService?

Tags: java, android, servicetestcase

I'm trying to build a valid junit testing suite on android.

Since i'm new to Junit i can't figure out how to use the ServiceTestCase class.

I can't figure it out how to get the getService() method working. it ever returns me null . So i decided to start it via startService. It does not work.

Could you please help me ?

Thanks

Comment: If someone answers your question it is customary to click the check mark next to their answer. Doing this will help you to get better answers faster.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is what you need to test your service

```
public class MyServiceTests extends ServiceTestCase<MyService> {

private static final String TAG = "MyServiceTests";

public MyServiceTests() {
    super(MyService.class);
}

/**
 * Test basic startup/shutdown of Service
 */
@SmallTest
public void testStartable() {
    Intent startIntent = new Intent();
    startIntent.setClass(getContext(), MyService.class);
    startService(startIntent);
    assertNotNull(getService());
}

/**
 * Test binding to service
 */
@MediumTest
public void testBindable() {
    Intent startIntent = new Intent();
    startIntent.setClass(getContext(), MyService.class);
    IBinder service = bindService(startIntent);
    assertNotNull(service);
}
}
```

I've written some articles about Android testing and test driven development that you may find useful, check  http://dtmilano.blogspot.com/search/label/test%20driven%20development.

Comment: Great answer still @dtmilano. Your work on android testing is quite interesting.

Comment: Do you actually have to run your app (which starts the service) first before you test your service?  I want to run your service test in isolation, but get a NullPointerException for the startIntent variable.

Comment: The Intent is created by `Intent startIntent = new Intent();`, cannot be null.

Comment: Excellent, I had been getting NullPointerExceptions and as it turns out all I needed was "getContext()".

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer doesn't work any more.

> TestCases like ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 or ServiceTestCase are
>   deprecated in favor of ActivityTestRule or ServiceTestRule.

[ATSL link](https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/rules/)

It seems they forgot to update the actual documentation.